# how can I truncate text and remove html tags in django template

Tags: django, django-templates

I've used `truncatechars` but if text contains a html tag, it will show the tag for me.

```
{{content.text|safe|truncatechars:140}}
```

for example displays something like this:

```
<p>hi</p>
```

I want to remove `p` tag.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Updated along with question:**

To completely remove the tags before truncating, use:

```
{{ content.text|striptags|truncatechars:140 }}
```

**Original answer:**

To ensure the tags are broken correctly, you'll want to use the [`truncatechars_html`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#truncatechars-html) template filter.

Comment: it worked, but how can I just display text? for example not images and etc.

Comment: I've updated. This new code should strip out all HTML tags.